# Screen doesn't turn back on after powersave

Tags: 12.04

I've run ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) for quite some time and I've never had any significant problem. Some days ago the update manager warned me about the HWE endlife support for ubuntu 12.04 and encouraged me to upgrade so I did. 
I didn't noticed any problem except for the touchpad which was not working anymore: I just needed to install the xserver-xorg-input-synapitic package which was strangely removed. What totally blew my mind is that when the screen (after 10 min in my settings) turns off to save power I cannot turn it back on either by pressing any key or moving the mouse. The only thing I can do is force reboot with alt+stamp+b. Even more strangely the suspend function works as a charm. Is the power saving mode for the screen that doesn't work any more.

I need your help since I don't know where to start to trouble shoot. I've attached a lshw output, hopefully it helps.

Thank you

PS: my laptop is a hp dv6-6156sl

PPS: if I close the lid I cannot turn the screen back on either :(

Comment: Try running `hwe-support-status` and see if that recommends anything.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Unity Dash and look for "Additional Drivers". Once the program opens, if there are proprietary drivers available for your graphics card besides the X.org driver, try using them. After installing one, you will need to reboot for changes to take effect.